# Count the minimum number of steps to change a number from m to n

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

I was on interview and was asked to solve this problem:

> Given 2 numbers `m` & `n` and we need to convert a number `m` to `n`
>   with minimum number of the following operations:
>
> - *-1* - Subtract 1
> - **2* - Multiply by 2
>
> For e.g. : if `m=4` and `n=6`, the program should output 2.
>
> - 1st operation : `-1 -> 4-1 = 3`.
> - 2nd operation : `*2 -> 3 * 2 =6`.
>
> As we can Change `m` (4) to `n` (6) after 2 operations, the answer is
>   2.

Now I have no idea what interviewer was expecting from me, also I have no clue what is a proper solution.

Comment: This was a question that i was asked in an interview and count not find any suitable algorithm to  go forward.

Comment: you may think this is student homework, but when you look on personal description .... .

Comment: @depperm That is a intuitive algorithm and will yield *a* solution but not the shortest one.

Comment: @Mohan You might want to edit your question to reflect that; otherwise people will think it's a homework question.

Comment: @depperm, i thought of that but this does not give the shortest path

Comment: @Mohan I don't know if it's the best solution, but you could use a basic [State space search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_space_search)

Comment: Wait, what? "Question seeking debugging help"? That's certainly not the correct clove reason, even if this question would be close worthy (which I'm not sure of, with a bit of editing it could be pretty good q)..

Comment: @Yksisarvinen yes strange reason to close

Comment: This fits well in my experience with the "algorithm" tag.  If you view it as an `algorithm` question, with Python and C++ as suggestions for expressing pseudocode, then I see no problem with this.  **I voted to reopen**.

Comment: Problem here is how this question is asked. At the beginning (before "interview" was added), it was looking like "do my homework for me" and that is why people voted to close it. Someone who claims has 4 years of experience and who is not new on SO (+2k points) should already know how to ask a good question. I will edit the question to made it more friendly and to stress context more.

Comment: @MarekR I agree with you, its just that i was in a little hurry when i put up this question. So did not give enough time and thought to frame the question in correct manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Try This:

```
def convert(m, n): 

    if(m == n): 
        return 0

    # only way is to do 
    # -1(m - n): times 
    if(m > n): 
        return m - n 

    # not possible 
    if(m <= 0 and n > 0): 
        return -1

    # n is greater and n is odd 
    if(n % 2 == 1): 

        # perform '-1' on m 
        #(or +1 on n): 
        return 1 + convert(m, n + 1) 

    # n is even 
    else: 

        # perform '*2' on m 
        #(or n/2 on n): 
        return 1 + convert(m, n / 2) 

# Driver code 
m = 3
n = 11
print("Minimum number of operations :", 
                          convert(m, n))
```

Answer (score 4):

This is my solution in java

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int m = 3;
    int n = 36;
    int counter = 0;
    float ntemp;

    if (m > n) {
        counter = m - n;
        System.out.println("result: " + counter);
        return;
    }

    while (m != n) {
        ntemp = n;
        while (m < ntemp) {
            ntemp = ntemp / 2;
        }
        if (m < ntemp + 1) {
            m = m * 2;
            System.out.println("*2");
        } else {
            m = m - 1;
            System.out.println("-1");
        }
        counter++;
    }
    System.out.println("result: " + counter);
}
}
```

Explanation:

Below I consider only cases where m < n, because case for given m >= n is obvious.

**1. If 2m > n**

In this case

a) if 2(m-1) = n -> end

b) if 2(m-1) < n

After subtract 1 we have too small number.

We can transform inequality:

2(m-1) < n -> **m < n/2 + 1**

If we have too small number, we have to multiply by 2, but it would be not optimal, because we have to subtract 2*(m-1) times (or 2*(m-2)-1 if n odd number), so it means that it wasn't good idea to substract 1.

Summarizing: For m < n/2 + 1 -> multiply and then subtract

**2. If 2m < n and 4m > n**

After some operations (one multiplication and some amount of -1) we want to receive result fulfilling condition from step 1.: m < n/2 + 1 (because we have to multiply once again).

We assumed 4m > n - > 2*2*m > n -> 2m > n/2.

When we change notation n/2 = ntemp, we recieve the same condition:

2m > ntemp, so we can get the same conclusions as in step 1.

**3. If x*m < n and 2*x*m > n, x-iteger**

Every number m we can transform like in step 2. and get the same conclusions.

P.S.: I know it's not formal proof and sorry for my English :)